# Need help in fixing this error "Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect"

Tags: authentication, ssl, oauth, gitlab

Need help in fixing this error

`Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect):`

this is logfile from /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log

i got this error when i'm trying to google auth to our gitlab-ce.

this is my environment:
 - CentOS 7
 - Gitlab 12.5

any help is appreciated :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You had a similar error reported in [gitlab-org/gitlab-foss issue 1924](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/1924):

> I had the exact same thing happen last night and it turned out that the `/etc/resolv.conf` within the Docker container was unreadable by the "`git`" user for the container.
>   This prevents it from resolving the host you're calling back to.

The ball started rolling after reading this issue:  [docker-gitlab issue 627](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/issues/627).

In your case, you might not use a GitLab within Docker, in which case, [check your proxy](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/issues/830#issuecomment-534931788).

Comment: Hi VonC,

did not use any docker here.
in my case i install the gitlab using yum installation in a barebone machine.

this happens when i login in to the gitlab via google authentication.
it seems when initiating auth via https 

`Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback?`

this error displays. and google auth wont proceed at all with 500 error

`Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect):`

thanks for the help